# Python list average value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
A=[100, 200, 300, 400,......]
B=[50, 110, 150, 210, 250,.........]
```

I want to average the elements in the list `B` within each elements of `A[i]` and `A[i+1]` and calculate the average by counting only those elements within the bound.

For example, to find and count all the numbers in list `A` within 100 to 200 it should add only `110 + 150` from list `B` and the average should be `(110 + 150) / 2` and so on for 200 to 300 etc.

I have written the code but it seems lengthy. Please help me with shorter methods.

Comment: *"I have written the code but it seems lengthy."* Please include it in the question anyway.

Comment: Along with what @kaya3 said, add expected output

Comment: if a value in list B is 200, would it be part of the first averaging (100-200), the second (200-300), or both?

Answer (score 2):

```
from statistics import mean
for lower, upper in zip(A, A[1:]):
    average = mean(x for x in B if lower <= x <= upper)
```

This will raise a [`statistics.StatisticsError`](https://docs.python.org/library/statistics.html#statistics.StatisticsError) if there are no elements within one of the windows, because you can't take the average of an empty list. If you want to handle that case, you need to catch the error

```
from statistics import mean, StatisticsError

for lower, upper in zip(A, A[1:]):
    try:
        average = mean(x for x in B if lower <= x <= upper)
    except StatisticsError:
        average = None
    print(average)
```

will print

```
130
230
None
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, all the other solutions have a time complexity of O(*mn*) where `A` has size *m* and `B` has size *n*, due to iterating over `B` for each adjacent pair of elements in `A`.

So here's a solution in O(*m* + *n* log *m*), iterating over `B` just once and using binary search to find the interval(s) which each number sits in:

```py
from bisect import bisect_left

def average_bins(a, b):
    num_bins = len(a) - 1
    sums = [0] * num_bins
    counts = [0] * num_bins

    for x in b:
        i = bisect_left(a, x)

        if i > 0 and i <= num_bins:
            sums[i-1] += x
            counts[i-1] += 1
        if i < num_bins and a[i] == x:
            sums[i] += x
            counts[i] += 1

    return [ (s/c if c else None) for s, c in zip(sums, counts) ]
```

If it's known that `A` is evenly spaced, this can be improved to O(*m* + *n*) by eliminating the need to do binary search; replace `i = bisect_left(a, x)` with `i = math.ceil((x - a[0]) / (a[1] - a[0]))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so,

```
avg = []
for j in range(0, len(A)-1):
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for element in B:
        if(element>=A[j] and element<=A[j+1]):
            sum+=element
            count+=1
    if(count!=0):
        avg.append(sum/count)
    else:
        avg.append(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
    lst = list(filter(lambda x: x > a[i]and x < a[i+1],b))
    avg = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,lst) / len(lst)
    print(avg)
```

The concept is to take two variables at a time: `a[i]`, `a[i+1]`.

`lst` filter function is to filter out the records, so that it contains the list of values which are greater than `a[i]` and less than `a[i+1]` avg variable, will actually calculate the sum of values in `lst` and then divide by number of variables to give the average.

Let me know if you want more clarity on the lambda functions.

Comment: the concept is to take two variables at a time...which is a[i], a[i+1] 

Then lst will use filter function is to filter out the records so that it contains the list of values which are greater than a[i] and less than a[i+1]

avg variable will actually calculate the sum of values in lst and then divide by number of variables to give the average, please let me know if you want more clarity on the lambda functions